# Importing data to google maps though Asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I build an example and made it run, but the problem is, that it only shows one of the markers instead of them both.

This is what is in my repeater.

12.545020 55.675020 , 12.388520 55.618460

My code looks like this

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>

             <asp:Label ID="lbl_Adresse" CssClass="LongitudeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Longitude")%>' />
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="LatitudeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Latitude")%>' />
             <asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="LocationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Adresse")%>' />
             <asp:Label ID="lbl_Fornavn" CssClass="Cust_NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Fornavn")%>' />
             <asp:Label ID="lbl_Titel" CssClass="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Titel")%>' />
             <asp:Label ID="Label3" CssClass="BilledeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Billede")%>' />
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" CssClass="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BrugerID")%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
```

,

my javascript look like this

```
var markers = { locationLatitude: "", locationLongitude: "", Cust_Name: "", Description: "" };
var markerArray = [];
window.onload = function () {

    var t = self.setTimeout(function () {

        var size = $('.LocationLabel').length;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            var id = $('.IDLabel').eq(i).text();
            var Location = $('.LocationLabel').eq(i).text();
            var CustName = $('.Cust_NameLabel').eq(i).text();
            var Description = $('.DescriptionLabel').eq(i).text();
            var Billede = $('.BilledeLabel').eq(i).text();
            markers.locationLatitude = $('.LatitudeLabel').eq(i).text();
            markers.locationLongitude = $('.LongitudeLabel').eq(i).text();
            markers.Cust_Name = CustName;
            markers.Description = "Navn: " + CustName + "<br />" + "Titel: " + Description + "<br />" + Billede + "<br />" + '<a href="Underviser.aspx?ProfilID=' + id + '">Se Profil</a>';

            markerArray.push(markers);

        }

        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers.locationLatitude, markers.locationLongitude),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
            var data = markerArray[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.locationLatitude, data.locationLongitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.Cust_Name
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.Description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    });
}
```

This example works, but it dont show all the markers on the map

Comment: It seems like maybe there is something wrong with my markerArray?

Comment: Yep its make a double of one marker instead of making two different